# PowerShell script exit code transition from 3rd party tool to TeamCity

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have PowerShell script which lunches command-line tool

```
     Set-Location "$env:HOMEDRIVE\Tool 1.0.6.5"
    .\tool.exe $or $do 0
```

This tool has 4 types of exit codes - 0, 1, 2, 3.

When I run this script in TeamCity, exit code of the script is always zero (success). I would like to sent other exit codes and mark test as "fail" in case any of 1, 2, 3 exit codes present in TeamCity Build Log.

How can I catch and sent exit codes to TeamCity via PowerShell methods?

Comment: Return the `$LastExitCode` variable after running the executable

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have tried such approach before and tried it now - same result - [Step 1/1] Process exited with code 0

I guess I can add Additional Failure Conditions and set values for exit codes there...

Comment: `.\tool.exe; exit $lastexitcode`?

Comment: I can't add anything to the line where I use my tool - it's command sensitive.

I have tried to add this exit $lastexitcode from the new line - it just closes PS script - but don't want to close it  - I want to transfer exit code to Team City Build Log.

Comment: Ok, the code is in TeamCity Build Log but when I have added custom rule - build fails if build log contains [Step 1/1] 2 text - but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (at least it works for the small script)

```
Set-Location "$env:HOMEDRIVE\Tool 1.0.6.5"
.\tool.exe $or $do 0
Write-Output "Exitcode $LASTEXITCODE"
```

What this script does:

1) Set location to folder where tool placed
  2) Start tool with parameters
  3) Write an output directly to console

In TeamCity I have added 3 rules:
  1) Build fails if build log contains text "Exitcode 1"
  2) Build fails if build log contains text "Exitcode 2"
  2) Build fails if build log contains text "Exitcode 3"

Also I have added text of failure message - it relates to exit code number and shows what has happened with build.